# Python's csv.writerow() is acting a tad funky

Tags: python, csv

From what I've researched, csv.writeRow should take in a list, and then write it to the given csv file. Here's what I tried:

```
from csv import writer
with open('Test.csv', 'wb') as file:
        csvFile, count = writer(file), 0
        titles = ["Hello", "World", "My", "Name", "Is", "Simon"]
        csvFile.writerow(titles)
```

I'm just trying to write it so that each word is in a different column.

When I open the file that it creates, however, I get the following message:

[image]

After pressing to continue anyways, I get a message saying that the file is either corrupted, or is a SYLK file. I can then open the file, but only after going through two error messages everytime I open the file.

Why is this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the code shown exactly what you're running?  It's a documented issue (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323626) that Excel will assume a csv file is SYLK if the first two characters are 'ID'.

Comment: version of windows/excel? I ran your code as posted and it works. The issue isn't present.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper You're 100% right, and I'm impressed as to how you figured that out. Didn't think the content of the list would make much of a difference.

Comment: It shouldn't, but Excel thinks it knows better than the extension.  To be fair, people expect it to be able to figure out cases where the extension really is wrong, but in a case like this assuming the extension is wrong, and then further assuming the file is corrupt when it doesn't appear corrupt if interpreted according to the extension is just mind-boggling.

Comment: As for figuring it out - I just googled "excel thinks csv is sylk".  I've seen it before myself but never cared enough to figure out the cause.

Comment: One thing to watch out for:  The "workaround" given by the Microsoft issue linked to by @PeterDeGlopper is to (manually) prepend an apostrophe into the file.  (This is also advice commonly found on the Web, including StackOverflow, to try to force CSV digits to be treated as strings rather than numbers.)  This is not what I'd call good advice, as that injects a literal apostrophe into your data.

Comment: Agreed - I linked the article to give a citation for the cause of the problem, but I don't agree with their recommendation.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Can you write this as an answer by any chance? That way I could accept it, making it easier for anyone else experiencing this problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a [documented issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323626) that Excel will assume a csv file is SYLK if the first two characters are 'ID'.

Venturing into the realm of opinion - it shouldn't, but Excel thinks it knows better than the extension. To be fair, people expect it to be able to figure out cases where the extension really is wrong, but in a case like this assuming the extension is wrong, and then further assuming the file is corrupt when it doesn't appear corrupt if interpreted according to the extension is just mind-boggling.

@John Y points out:

> One thing to watch out for: The "workaround" given by the Microsoft issue linked to by @PeterDeGlopper is to (manually) prepend an apostrophe into the file. (This is also advice commonly found on the Web, including StackOverflow, to try to force CSV digits to be treated as strings rather than numbers.) This is not what I'd call good advice, as that injects a literal apostrophe into your data.

@DSM suggests using `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` on the writer.  Excel is not confused by a file beginning with `"ID"` rather than `ID`, so if the other tools that are going to work with the CSV accept that quoting level this is probably the best solution other than just ignoring Excel's confusion.

Comment: Would forcing quotes with `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` work?

Comment: @DSM, it does seem that it would prevent the file from starting with `ID` so it's worth a shot.

Comment: @DSM - I tested it, and it does prevent the SYLK mis-identification.  So if that's acceptable to whatever else is working with the csv file that's probably the best solution.

Comment: This is super helpful. I had this problem, and just ended up renaming the first heading to a more specific name ID --> CustomerID, although the quotes is probably the right thing to do if you don't have the luxury of renaming the first ID header